# Python loop is failing to detect the use of certain files within each dir

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a loop running to loop through a directory, and then trying to determine if the following files exist or not... if they do, do something different with each:

```
rawsource="CODE_BASE/" 
for repo_dir in os.listdir(rawsource):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rawsource, repo_dir)):
        os.chdir(a_dir)
        if os.path.isfile('requirements.txt'):
            print("python")
        elif os.path.isfile('pom.xml'):
            print("java")
        elif os.path.isfile('package.json'):
            print("js")
        else:
            print("didnt find python, java or js")
```

For some reason when I do this, it always hits the `else`. Why is that?

Comment: Should the like for `package.json` be `if` or `elif`?

Comment: sorry typo now updated

Comment: What is `a_dir`? The files are looked for there. Did you mean `os.chdir(os.path.join(rawsource, repo_dir))`. Or simply avoid using `os.chdir` and relative paths and just pass full paths: `if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(rawsource, repo_dir, 'requirements.txt')):`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to search for files in folders in the base directory, is that right? If so, you could just use os.listdir() again with the path to the folder in the base directory and check the filenames of the contents of that folder

Comment: @WesselOttevanger - this is right, can you provide an answer with an example in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
rawsource="CODE_BASE/" 
for repo_dir in os.listdir(rawsource):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rawsource, repo_dir)):
        dir_files = os.listdir(os.path.join(rawsource, repo_dir))
        for file in dir_files:
            if file == "requirements.txt":
                print("python")
            elif file == "pom.xml":
                print("java")
            elif file == "package.json":
                print("js")
            else:
                print("didnt find python, java or js")
```

This will search the base directory CODE_BASE/ for folders, if it has found a folder it will search that folder for the specified files.